# Salesforce License Info

Tags: customer-community, licenses, login, userlicense

Our employees/contractors need authenticated access to submit user requests.They may use max 10 times in an Year.Users needs access to Read only to Accounts,Read Write to Contacts and Custom Objects.Should I go for Customer Community Login based licenses ?

https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=users_license_types_communities.htm&language=en_US

What is the best salesforce license for these kind of users ?

Comment: Which objects do they need access to in Salesforce? That can affect the choice a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Licenses that look like they meet your criteria are Force.com-One App, force.com App subscription, and Company community User. You may want to use the company community option since they only login a few times a year. This will allow access to Accounts, contacts, cases, and documents along with up to 10 custom objects and 10 custom tabs. Please see the link below for more information on license types.
https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=users_license_types_available.htm&language=en_US

Comment: Users just need read only access to Accounts and readwrite to Contacts and Custom objects..Do I still go for Platform licenses

Comment: I think that looks suitable as it would be possible to match the necessary permissions using the OWD for Platform users.

Comment: Users may use max of 10 times in an year ... what about customer community login based licenses

Comment: If that is the case the Force.com-One App license may also work for you, but those users will only have access to one custom app whereas with the platform license they would have access to all custom apps.

Comment: Just need access to submit a user request form from salesforce.

Comment: From the description in the link Company Community User license could work for you as well. I'm not as familiar with those licenses and I worry about limitations that may not be listed there, but according to your requirements it looks like that could work too.

Comment: Salesforce Platform license has been discontinued (that is what we were told by the sales person. Salesforce licenses page doesn't say that). They recommended us Force.Com- One App licenses as alternative. They are expensive compared to platform licenses.

Answer (score 1):

I believe now they are offering them (`Force.com-One App`, `Force.com App subscription`, and `Company Community User`) in the same bucket under **`App Cloud`** flavor (and also as `Employee Communtiy`) and it's called **`Employee Apps and Community` $25/mo** and it provides Read/Write access to `Accounts` and `Contacts`, but none other CRM standard objects, and also up to 10 `Custom Objects`. There is also more expensive `Apps Plus` license $75/mo that allows to use 100 `Custom Objects` with each user license. More details can be found here - [App Cloud Pricing](https://www.salesforce.com/editions-pricing/app-cloud/). There is a [link to the pdf file at the bottom](https://www.salesforce.com/content/dam/web/en_us/www/documents/pricing/salesforce-app-cloud-pricing-editions.pdf) where you can see the App licenses comparison in more details.

In regard of `Customer Community` - it can't be used by internal employees as we were told by our account representative when we are doing the research, and migrated to Force.com (aka App Cloud) platform.